# Is there a way to cache a python module in excel?

Tags: python, excel, vba, import, xlwings

I'm currently learning the python library xlwings with the goal of being able to use python functions in excel. To test it out, I made a button in excel that runs a Visual Basic script that executes a python function that raises the value of the selected cell by one:

```
Sub MyMacro()
    RunPython ("import LearnXlwings; LearnXlwings.add_one(" & "'" & ActiveCell.Address & "'" & ")")
End Sub
```

My python code is as follows:

```
import xlwings

def add_one(cell):
    wb = xlwings.Book.caller()
    wb.sheets[0].range(cell).value += 1
```

This function works, and the value of the selected cell (if it's a number) gets raised by one. However, it takes quite a bit of time to run, which I suspect is because of the line

```
import xlwings
```

Is there a way I can import xlwings with a VBA script, and then keep it cached so that my macro doesn't have to re-import it every time it runs?

Comment: Is it any faster if you change `import xlwings` to `from xlwings import Book` ?

Comment: @JacobIRR seems to be slightly faster, but there's still a noticeable delay, which appears when I enter that in an interactive shell as well. There might also just be a delay inherent to excel-python communication. Thanks for your suggestion, though

Comment: Use UDFs or use the UDF server also for RunPython, see: http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/addin.html#global-settings